# enable Advanced Digitizing Panel (cadDockwidget) with PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, digitizing, cad

I am working on a PyQgis Plugin where I want to enable cad in advanced digitizing panel. Following pre-conditions are met:

- layer is in edit mode
- project has projected crs
- move feature tool is activated (`iface.actionMoveFeature()`)

I found that the way to activate cad tool is the following way:
`iface.cadDockWidget().enable()`

But it does not work reliably in my case. Sometimes the cad tool is enabled and sometimes not. For the cases it is not activate with the python command, I was always able to enable it by clicking the button in the panel, which means there should not be a problem which prevents it from enabling.

Any idea what the reason could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
iface.cadDockWidget().enable()
```

you are not activating it, you are simply making the icon clickable. Using `.disable()` would make it unclickable.

Instead you should *trigger* the icon which is the equivalent of clicking the icon using code:

```
for x in iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().actions():
    if x.text() == 'Enable advanced digitizing tools':
        x.trigger()
```

---

*Note: There doesn't seem to be an `objectName()` associated with this icon in order to identify it succinctly so we use the text.*

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3.26.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 it seems to me that there is no text, but an object name...

```
for x in iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().actions():
    if x.objectName() == 'mEnableAction':
        x.trigger()
```